# How can I number the section titles automatically in Mathematica?

Tags: document-creation

When I write a document in Mathematica, I do not like to number the section title myself, because I usually add or delete a section from time to time. Is there a way that Mathematica can number the section for me automatically, just like what LaTeX does(in LaTeX, I only need to enter \begin{section}, and it is automatically numbered)?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7234720/656841) will be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation on [Automatic Numbering](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AutomaticNumbering.html) mentions how to number section titles automatically.

Section numbers can be tracked by creating an automatic numbering object linked to a counter. This can be done using the menu commands in the notebook interface: [Insert --> Automatic Numbering](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/AutomaticNumbering.html). The created object updates automatically if sections are moved or deleted, and copying the section cell duplicates the object, so you should be able to go through the menus and create a section numbering object once and copy/paste the section cell to get numbered sections.